# Mongo DB Index name

Tags: mongodb

I created mongo db collection index using java code

```
dbCollection.createIndex("accountNumber");
```

When i see indices using

```
db.accounts.getIndexes()
```

I am getting the index name as **"accountNumber_1"**

How to get the index name also same as document field? or how to give index name?

Is naming indices important or i can ignore this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you need to use the index name? When you `hint` to mongo which index to use in a query, you specify the *field name* that is indexed - not the actual index name: `db.users.find().hint( { age: 1 } )`

Comment: you can ignore this. the name is of no consequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we create index on the document `users`

```
> db.users.createIndex({name: 1})
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Index with name: name_1 already exists with different option
s",
        "code" : 85
}
```

the `name: name_1` is returned, then we can get the index through `getIndexes()`

```
> db.users.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.users"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "name" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name_1",
                "ns" : "test.users",
                "background" : true,
                "safe" : null
        }
]
```

We know, the `name_1` is just the value of index `name`. and the key `name` is used to create index for document `users`. I think the `name_1` is the value of `name` to meet `BSON` structure. We can ignore it...

Answer (score 0):

You can create index with the name you wanted using the other variant of createIndex method, refer java API [here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#createIndex-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-).

```
public void createIndex(DBObject keys,
                        DBObject options)
Creates an index on the field specified, if that index does not already exist.
Prior to MongoDB 3.0 the dropDups option could be used with unique indexes allowing documents with duplicate values to be dropped when building the index. Later versions of MongoDB will silently ignore this setting.
```

Parameters:
keys - a document that contains pairs with the name of the field or fields to index and order of the index
options - a document that controls the creation of the index.
MongoDB documentation
Index Creation Tutorials

You can corresponding mongodb documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#definition).

Basically the second parameter 'options' contain an option to supply index name explicitly.